# Congruence of $29^p \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

For how many primes p we have: $p \mid 29^p+1$

My attempt: $p \mid 29^p+1 \rightarrow  29^p\equiv -1\pmod p \rightarrow (29^p)^2\equiv (-1)^2\pmod p$
Which gives us: $$29^{2p}\equiv 1\pmod p $$That is true iff:$$\phi(p)\mid2p \rightarrow p-1\mid2p$$Since $p-1|p$ only for $p=2$, for $p>2$ we have $p-1\mid2$ i.e. $p=3$, thus this leads to: $p=2,3$ as only solutions.

I checked the solution to the problem, turns out $p=5$ also works (so $p=2,3,5$ are all the solutions), checking for my arguement we would have $5-1\mid2\cdot5$ which is clearly incorrect... why is my arguement wrong?

Comment: From Fermat's little theorem, we have $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$. So $a^p+1\equiv a+1\pmod p$ etc.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yeah so $29^p+1\cong 30\cong 0 \pmod p$ and we get the result by factoring 30, but I want to know why my arguement is wrong not how to get the answer

Comment: I don't see how you get from $29^{2p}\equiv1$ to $\phi(p)\mid 2p$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oh, I've done a silly mistake, I was think about the order of 29 modulo p that has to divide 2p, but it would imply that $\phi(p) | 2p$ if 29 is a primitive root modulo p, my bad...